# Trying to find objects that are capturing the row lock, bulk data load jobs, failed flows, etc

Tags: visual-workflow, exception, platform-event, bulk-api

I'm trying to monitor the below issues. Could someone please help us to get insights on which object the below information gets captured.

- Row lock errors/issues
- Bulk Data load Jos errors/issues
- Audit Trail
- Failed Flows
- Batch Job errors and issues
- Platform Events

I know EventLogFile object captures many event types. But, apart from this object, are there any other objects that can be used to do monitoring and debug the above listed issues.

**You can go ahead and close after you answer this question. Merely flagging this to "close" will never help anyone. BTW where is the community so I can post this question?**

Comment: What have you found in your research so far?  Have you looked at this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_list.htm)?

Comment: @DavidCheng I've extracted EventLogFile using this Heroku app https://salesforce-elf.herokuapp.com/ . I tried to find Audit Trail, Row Lock errors and the other issues listed above, but not able to find it in EventLogFile. I don't have a clue which object capturing these details.

Comment: You're aware that you need to [purchase the Shield product](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387928&type=1) to get the full Event Monitoring feature?  Have you checked [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_supportedeventtypes.htm) on the event types covered by Event Monitoring?